# Text data type Issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this code below and when I run it, I get an error

> Column "Orders.User_Memo1" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

So then I add `o.User_Memo1` (or simply remove `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX)`) and I get the following error message:

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator

So I'm basically stuck, I'm getting errors no matter what I do, excluding it, including it, and including it with a CONVERT all give me errors.  What are my options?

```
SELECT
    CAST(o.OrderNo AS INT) AS [OrderNo], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST(SUBSTRING(od.User_Memo1, 
    CHARINDEX('Pack',od.User_Memo1)+5, 8) AS DATE), 1) AS [Prod Due Date],
    o.User_Date1 AS [3 Week Ack Date],
    o.User_Date2 AS [1 Week Ack Date],
    CASE 
       WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), o.User_Memo1) LIKE '%RDS%' 
          THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST(SUBSTRING(od.User_Memo1, CHARINDEX('RSD', od.User_Memo1) + 4, 8) AS DATE), 1) 
          ELSE NULL
    END AS [Revised Ship Date],
    d.ShipDate
FROM 
    Orders o 
JOIN 
    OrderDet od ON o.OrderNo = od.OrderNo
LEFT JOIN 
    DelTicket d ON o.OrderNo = d.OrderNo
WHERE 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), o.User_Memo1) IS NOT NULL
    AND SUBSTRING(o.User_Memo1, 1, 3) = 'Cut'
GROUP BY 
    o.OrderNo, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST(SUBSTRING(od.User_Memo1, CHARINDEX('Pack', od.User_Memo1) + 5, 8) AS DATE), 1), 
    o.User_Date1, o.User_Date2, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), o.User_Memo1), CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST(SUBSTRING(od.User_Memo1, CHARINDEX('RSD', od.User_Memo1) + 4, 8) AS DATE), 
1), 
    d.ShipDate
ORDER BY 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(o.User_Memo1, CHARINDEX('Pack',o.User_Memo1) + 5, 8) AS DATETIME) DESC;
```

Comment: That code gives me a headache. You need to try and explain more.

Comment: The difference that I see is in the `Group By` your casting it as `Date` in the `Order By` your casting as `DateTime`. And in the `Group By` you are specifying the `OrderDet` table `od.User_Memo1`, not `Orders`.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `cast` in your `where` clause. try changing it to this

```
AND CAST(Substring(o.user_memo1, 1, 3) as varchar(3)) = 'Cut'
```

*Complete Query*

```
SELECT Cast(o.orderno AS INT) AS [OrderNo], 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), Cast(Substring(od.user_memo1, Charindex('Pack', od.user_memo1) + 5, 8) AS  DATE), 1)    AS [Prod Due Date], 
       o.user_date1                                                                                                  AS [3 Week Ack Date], 
       o.user_date2                                                                                                  AS [1 Week Ack Date], 
       CASE 
         WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), o.user_memo1) LIKE '%RDS%' 
         THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), Cast(Substring(od.user_memo1, Charindex('RSD', od.user_memo1) + 4, 8) AS DATE), 1) 
         ELSE NULL 
       END                                                                                                          AS [Revised Ship Date], 
       d.shipdate 
FROM orders o 
JOIN orderdet od ON o.orderno = od.orderno 
LEFT JOIN delticket d  ON o.orderno = d.orderno 
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), o.user_memo1) IS NOT NULL 
       AND  CAST(Substring(o.user_memo1, 1, 3) as varchar(3)) = 'Cut' 
GROUP  BY o.orderno, 
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), Cast(Substring(od.user_memo1,  Charindex('Pack', od.user_memo1) + 5, 8) AS DATE), 1), 
          o.user_date1, 
          o.user_date2, 
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), o.user_memo1), 
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), Cast(Substring(od.user_memo1,  Charindex('RSD', od.user_memo1) + 4, 8) AS  DATE), 1), 
          d.shipdate 
ORDER  BY Cast(Substring(o.user_memo1, Charindex('Pack', o.user_memo1) + 5, 8) AS DATETIME) DESC;
```